# App Actions test tool with google assistant shows "Sorry, I couldn't find it"

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

I am facing the [issue](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin/issues/6) while running the app actions fitness sample with App Actions test tool, the assistant says "Sorry, I couldn't find that"

Steps Followed:

1. Uploaded the APK to play store internal test track in draft mode
2. Logged in with same account to **(Device, PlayConsole and AndroidStudio)**
3. Changed the **packageId** to the app which I have uploaded to
   playstore
4. Running App Actions Test Tool -> **Preview uploaded
   successfully**
5. **Run** -> Opens Assistant in device with message **'Sorry,
   Couldn't find that'**

Answer (score 5):

In my case, The Google assistant has different language. I changed to English - United States.

**To change the language,**

**Step 1:** I said, "Hey Google, open Assistant settings"

**Step 2:** In Assistant settings -> Select "Assistant" -> Select "Languages -> It was **English (India)**   -> Just click that -> change to **English (United States)**

Then the "App Actions Test Tool" working fine.

Comment: It would have been a tricky fix without this solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: It's not working for me i have created assistant link in English language.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few more things to verify. The two pieces of information that are important to check match up are the package name, let's use **`com.sample.app`** as an example and the Google account, let's use **`sample@gmail.com`** as an example.

Verify package name matches up:

- You should have `com.sample.app` as an app in your Play Console account for `sample@gmail.com` (it can be in any track)
- You should have the `com.sample.app` APK installed on your test device
- You should have an actions.xml in the source code for the app with package `com.sample.app` - you should run the App Actions Test Tool from this project

Verify the Google account matches up:

- You should be logged into Android Studio with `sample@gmail.com`
- You should be logged into your test device with `sample@gmail.com`, you should also have Google Assistant set up with the same account (ensure you can trigger Google Assistant for that account)

You should also verify:

- You can successfully trigger the defined Android deep links defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml` (the ones that `actions.xml` will call), see [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/quickstart#deeplink) for how to test using `adb`. You could also specify your package name in the `adb` command to test even more accurately how Assistant will call your app.

If you still have issues, try looking at `adb logcat` for the exact `Intent` that Assistant is trying to call. Note that you will need to turn off a filter for your package name if you are looking in Android Studio. The log will come from the Google Search app (which is what runs Assistant). It should hopefully tell you the package name and Android `Intent` params it is trying to call your app with, which will let you work out what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Logging into Google Assistant with the same account did the trick for me. Whew, this is so complicated to test.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for quick response. Now I am able to see the Android Slices and App Actions via google assistant. It started working I just checked all me configuration and everything looks good.

**Steps I performed:**

- Checked all my logins (Test Device, Play Console and Android Studio)
- Freshly installed the application with the package name which was
  uploaded to playstore.*(Comment the actions meta-data and then upload the app to play console otherwise it won't allow to upload)*
- Deleted actions preview and updated again from AATT.(App Actions Test
  Tool)
- Run the command it started launching the app via google assistant and
  showing the slice from app inside google assistant window.

***Just a quick query how can i trigger the voice commands for the same instead of adb command generated by AATT?***

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I added a comment answering this here: https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin/issues/8#issuecomment-531981777

On stackoverflow, you should leave comments below the answer if you need further clarifications (vs adding a new answer like this one).

Comment: Refer this blog created for app-actions and slices implementation https://medium.com/@harshfast/android-implementing-app-actions-and-slices-3fea2c2124c4

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked after checking these two things-

1. The account should be owner on google play console.
2. The locale on your device should match to what you are choosing in Test Tool. In my case it was English(UK) and after changing it to English(US), it started working.