# App Action not running with App Actions Test Tool

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions

I'm trying to run the sample [App Actions Fitness project](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin) but I can't get the AATT to execute any actions on my Samsung S8 device (or Emulator Pixel 3 with Android 10 & Google Assistant).
I've tried with AATT versions (3.1.1 & 3.1.2).

These are the steps i followed:

1. Uploaded a signed draft application to my internal test track Google
   Play Store account without `actions.xml` in the AndroidManifest file.
2. Installed the signed application with `actions.xml` in the manifest
   onto my device
3. I'm running the latest version of the Assistant and the Google App
4. I made sure the Assistant is properly setup
5. I logged into my Google Play Store account, device/Assistant and
   Android Studio using the same account.
6. Created a preview successfully using the AATT using `Fit Actions` as
   my invocation name and left the Locale blank.
7. When i Run the AATT the Assistant is launched on the device but
   says, `Sorry, I couldn't find it`

I even tried to verify my setup using the suggested steps by @adamkoch on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57951935/268156) and that didn't work.

I searched the `adb logcat` for the exact `Intent` that Assistant is trying to call but only found this:

```
I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=null flg=0x10000000 cmp=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.deeplink.DeeplinkActivityEntrypoint}} from uid 2000
```

Any thoughts and suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Can you post the exact version of the Google Search App? And also you should first get it working with the emulator and then try on the S8 (just to rule out that there's any issues with the device). For the emulator, make sure you use the recommended image (with Play Store etc)

Comment: Also, did you make any changes to the sample code from github except the package name?

And what locale is your device set to? en-US? or something else?

Lastly, make sure you can trigger the intents correctly via `adb` (as per the other stackoverflow post you linked to.

Comment: @AdamK Samsung Galaxy S8 (Google Search App - v10.94.12.21.arm64). Emulator Pixel 3a API 28 including Play Store (Google Search App - v10.94.12.21.x86). I didn't make any changes to the project except package name. I'm able to trigger the intents correctly. So I got the sample app working on the S8, the issue was the locale. I changed it to en-US. Using the same configuration for the S8 on the Emulator i can't get it to work, but at least it works on the device :-)

Comment: Ok glad you got it working on the S8. Not sure what the problem with the emulator is.

Comment: Actually I found out that testing App Actions previews on the emulator doesn't currently work so you should use a real device like the S8 until that issue is resolved. Not easy to find but it is mentioned here:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/test-tool#limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, everything was verified and looked good as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936224/app-actions-test-tool-with-google-assistant-shows-sorry-i-couldnt-find-it/57951935#57951935). The one thing missing on the Samsung Galaxy S8 was to check/set the device locale - the safest bet is to set to en-US.

App Actions is [supported in other locales](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/test-tool#locale_support) (but en-US is always a safe bet to verify your test setup).

Testing App Actions previews on the emulator is not currently supported which is why it only worked on the physical device (mentioned in the [limitations](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/test-tool#limitations) section).