# how to test android slices using google assistant for my app

Tags: java, android, mobile, google-assistant, android-slices

When using AATT-App Action Test Tool for android slices. I'm getting slice in google assistant but when it comes to direct voice search or typing my event name, the slices are not able to appear like using in AATT. pls give me some answers to resolve this issue. isn't dialog flow required for this types in GA?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below links to troubleshoot your issue the problem seems similar and already reported in these questions and github issues.

[Assistant shows “Sorry, I couldn't find it”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936224/app-actions-test-tool-with-google-assistant-shows-sorry-i-couldnt-find-it)

Github: [Not able to open the app through google assistant](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin/issues/6)

Github: [Action not work via Assistant](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin/issues/8#issuecomment-531981777)