# "Sorry, couldn't get it" error with Actions test tool

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, app-actions, google-assistant, android-slices

I have followed all the steps mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57951935/8483843 and also using the `en-US` locale in the test tool but still getting this issue.
I am currently integrating Slices with App actions using a custom intent. Here's the code - https://github.com/tronku/ResTest

The release apk is already in draft mode on the play console with the same account as Google assistant and Android Studio.
Please let me know if I am missing something or implemented things wrongly.

**Steps Followed:**

- Uploaded the AAB to PlayStore in draft mode.
- Using the same account to (Google assistant, PlayConsole and Android Studio)
- Running App Actions Test Tool -> Preview uploaded successfully
  Run -> Opens Assistant in device with message 'Sorry, Couldn't find that'

Comment: When you create a question, there is a step by step guide in the right column. Please follow it.

Comment: Have you verified that you are logged in and can access the Assistant on the test device (or in the emulated device)?

Comment: @ToniCorinne yeah, I have verified that too.

Comment: A couple of observations:


1. Test first with App Actions test tool (AATT), then try Assistant, only after AATT works.

2. [The test queries in your sample](https://github.com/tronku/ResTest/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/arrays.xml#L5-L10) shouldn't include the app name in them. Please follow [the docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/custom-intents#query-patterns:~:text=%22Hey%20Google%2C%20open%20ExampleGameApp%20and%20start%20making%20a%20cake.%22,ExampleGameApp%20to%20produce%20cake%205%20times.%22) to learn more.

Comment: Also, is there a reason why you picked a custom intent over [GET_ORDER BII](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/get-order)?

Comment: @Diego I am testing on AATT only, that tool opens Assistant while testing. I have changed the intent to GET_ORDER also, but getting the same "not find" error.

Comment: Thanks, @tronku, for confirming that you're using AATT and changed to GET_ORDER. Could run [this checklist](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/troubleshoot#test_5) to spot any other issues?

Comment: Yeah @Diego , followed all the steps in the checklist. I am just using slices so there should be no need of deeplink, just using content://. Also, is there anything important in console? I have uploaded the aab in internal testing track as a draft only.

Comment: Could you try replicating this issue using the [Fitness sample app](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/res/xml/actions.xml#L50-L52)? I wonder if something got lost in translation.

Comment: @Diego i tried the same with fitness app, still getting the same error. I am creating a draft in internal testing. What am I missing here?